# TV show that had a golden lion with three tails, summoned by a red gem on the side of the main character's pants

Tags: story-identification, tv, anime

TV show that had a golden lion with three tails, summoned by a red gem on the side of the main character's pants.  The main character was a kid that lived in a different world.

1. There was a battle on a riverside in the city where the villain was a female that had a giant bee.
2. That villain had a twin brother.

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies the show you're looking for, please mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. Or if the only answers posted are incorrect, please indicate that with a comment so we know to keep looking. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Might this be ***[Zinba](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31427/Zinba)***...?

> The juvenile Kan from the earth is summoned to the Kingdom of Toria , where he encounters attack from the giant creature Zinba, and he's rescued by the linker Shibuki and Uranus. Later, he accidentally gets on the linker squad DUX truck to the maze valley, finding in a cave a golden Zinba.

The main character is, [Tian Yu](https://myanimelist.net/character/140123/Tian_Yu), a boy from Earth who is transported to another world. He later finds a red gem which allows him to control a Zinba; a golden or yellow lion-like beast with two tails. In subsequent episodes, Tian Yu carries the gem on a keychain attached to his shorts.

In the third and fourth episodes, Tian Yu and his Zinba battle a giant bee or wasp-like creature, controlled by a girl with red hair. The girl is accompanied by a boy with brown hair, who may or may not be her brother.